# Existence of natural equivalence

Tags: category-theory

Let $S : C\rightarrow  D$ and $T : D \rightarrow C$ be covariant functors and $α : S \rightarrow T$ a natural equivalence. Show
that there is a natural equivalence $β : T \rightarrow S$ such that $βα = I_S$ and $βα = I_T$ , where $I_S : S \rightarrow S$
is the identity natural equivalence, and similarly for $I_T$.

I think there is a problem with that functors. I got in my script that natural equivalence works on functors which have same domain and codomain. 
If you explain it to me, you can give me a hint how to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: You're right, natural transformations are only defined between functors with the same domain and codomain. And what you're asked to prove is the definition of natural isomorphism... Is that an exercise from a book? Are you sure it's written this way?

Comment: This is exercise from my professor. I will write to him then and find out what is going on.